# Hydrogen visible transitions

Tags: physical-chemistry, hydrogen

When dealing with electrons and the electromagnetic spectrum, why are there only four visible transitions in the hydrogen atom?

Answer (score 6):

This all falls back to the [hydrogen absorption spectra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series). There are multiple "series" discovered by different scientists. The series in the visible region is the [Balmer series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series).

Since the electronic energy levels of the hydrogen atom are [*quantized*](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/35660/5017), there can only be certain discrete transitions.

As it turns out, if you solve the Balmer series (n=2), you get:

$$\frac{1}{\lambda} = \frac{4}{B}\left(\frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}\right) = R_\mathrm{H}\left(\frac{1}{2^2} - \frac{1}{n^2}\right) \quad \mathrm{for~} n=3,4,5,...$$

You will then get lines at $\lambda$ = 656.3 nm, 486.1 nm, 434.1 nm, 410.2 nm...

Only a few of those fall in the visible. The [Lyman series (n=1)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman_series) occurs in the UV spectra, and the [Paschen series (n=3)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_spectral_series#Paschen_series_.28Bohr_series.3B_n.E2.80.B2_.3D_3.29) occurs in the IR.